# Последовательно достать строки с файла формата txt

Tags: ios, swift, файлы, xcode

У меня есть текстовый файл. Его содержимое например такое.

```
1. Первая строка#
2. Вторая строка#
3. n-я строка#
```

Есть для считывания такой метод.

```
func getDataFromFile(name: String , type:String) -> String {
    let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
    let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let  randomContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).randomElement()!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
    return randomContent
}
```

C этим методом я могу считывать только рандомно строки, к тому же они повторяются. Как я могу  считывать последовательно? Пример : у меня есть 10 строк, я считываю с 1-й по 10-ю и после этого например вывожу что уже каждая строка была извлечена с файла.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778700/read-a-text-file-line-by-line-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы итак извлекаете все необходимые данные в `getDataFromFile(name:type:)`. Просто возвращайте из этой функции все полученные строки. Вот как должна выглядеть `getDataFromFile` в таком случае:

```
func getDataFromFile(name: String , type: String) -> [String] {
    let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
    let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let fullContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") }
    return fullContent
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
let stringsFromFile = getDataFromFile(name: "file", type: "txt")
stringsFromFile.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: Значит я сначала все достаю и потом как с масивом могу работать ? Спасибо )

Comment: @JiosDev Именно так. `randomElement()` здесь явно ни к месту.

Comment: У меня возникла ошибка когда я попытался реализовать ваш метод. ПРикреплю код и ошибку  к вопросу.

Comment: @JiosDev Лучше новый вопрос задайте.

Comment: @JiosDev Пожалуйста, откатите изменения в Вашем вопросе, так будет проще разобраться в том, что Вы хотите выяснить. Для решения проблемы с `replacingOccurrences` создайте новую тему.

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110407/replace-occurrences-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)