# Replace occurrences в масиве

Tags: массивы, ios, swift, файлы

Содержимое файла.

```
1. @NAME1  прыгает через @NAME2#
2. Все игроки молчат.#
3. @NAME1 делает 10 отжиманий.#
```

Я должен начать с первой строки, когда я нахожу в строке @NAME1 или @NAME 2 я заменяю именами которые вводят игроки ранее. Если нет @NAME1, то вывожу строку и ничего не меню. И так далее.

Раньше я мог считать строку с файла, затем заменить имена в этой строке. При каждом нажатии на кнопку, я получал рандомную строку.

Метод выглядел вот так.

```
func getDataFromFile(name: String , type:String) -> String {
    let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
    let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let  randomContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).randomElement()!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
    return randomContent
}
```

Затем нужно было переделать чтобы считывалось последвовательно, и метод был переделан вот так.

```
func getDataFromFile(name: String , type: String) -> [String] {
    let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
    let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let fullContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") }
    return fullContent
}

let stringsFromFile = getDataFromFile(name: "file", type: "txt")
stringsFromFile.forEach {
   $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME1", with: firstName!, options: .literal, range: nil)
   $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME2", with: secondName!, options: .literal, range: nil)

      playerLabel.text = $0
}
```

Теперь почему то мне показывает одну строку без имён и когда я пытаюсьпоказать следующую строку, ничего не происходит.

Comment: Скорее всего, `playerLabel` - объект класса `UILabel`, и он у Вас один, а элементов в `stringsFromFile` может быть много. Что конкретно Вы хотите отображать в `playerLabel`?

Comment: Если я получил все элементы в масив. То нужно при нажатии кнопки брать строку, проверять есть ли там имена и потом выводить это в лейбл. И так по одной строке

Comment: У вас сейчас в лейбл поочередно попадают все значения из массива и в конце концов должно остаться последнее

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример файла file.txt.

Comment: Я  добавил в вопросе

Comment: Вам нужно при каждом нажатии на кнопку показывать следующую строку  из массива или как?

Comment: Да. В идеале брать  элемент из массива -> получать его индекc ->  отображать строку в uilabel ->  удалить из массива строку по сохраненному индексу 
 -> повторять пока массива не будет пустой.

Comment: Все описанные действия Вы производите в потомке `UIViewController`?

Comment: Метод где считывается файл в массив это отдельный класс. Вызываю массив для использования уже в VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявите `stringsFromFile` как свойство Вашего потомка `UIViewController`:

```
let stringsFromFile = Self.getDataFromFile(name: "file", type: "txt")
```

Для того, чтобы устранить ошибки компиляции в данной строчке, сделайте `getDataFromFile(name:type:)` статической:

```
static func getDataFromFile(name: String , type: String) -> [String] {
    let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
    let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let fullContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "") }
    return fullContent
}
```

Добавьте новой свойство `var currentStringsFromFileIndex = 0` для отслеживания текущей позиции в массиве `stringsFromFile`.

Насколько я понял, у вас есть кнопка, нажимая на которую должна обрабатываться следующая строка из `stringsFromFile`. Тогда у функции для обработки нажатия должен быть такой код:

```
@objc func onButtonTap(sender: UIButton) {
    guard stringsFromFile.indices.contains(currentStringsFromFileIndex) else { // Проверяем, существует ли элемент с индексом currentStringsFromFileIndex
        return
    }
    playerLabel.text = stringsFromFile[currentStringsFromFileIndex]
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME1", with: firstName!, options: .literal, range: nil)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME2", with: secondName!, options: .literal, range: nil)
    currentStringsFromFileIndex += 1
}
```

Теперь при нажатии на кнопку у `playerLabel` будет меняться отображаемый текст.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ мне подходит немного больше, отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Я проверил ваш пример, в нем были ошибки

- строки не отображались, так как в них содержались переносы строки `\n` в начале строк, соответственно при выводе в лейбл сама строка переносилась и была не видна.
- исправлена замена шаблонов в строках

Также я добавил удаление пустых строк.

Помимо этого здесь приведена логика показа и последующего удаления строк из массива при каждом нажатии на кнопку

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var playerLabel: UILabel!

    var stringsFromFile = [String]()
    let firstName = "Name 1"
    let secondName = "Name 2"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadStrings()
    }

    func loadStrings() {
        stringsFromFile = getDataFromFile(name: "file", type: "txt")
        stringsFromFile = stringsFromFile.map {
            var result = $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME1", with: firstName, options: .literal, range: nil)
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME2", with: secondName, options: .literal, range: nil)
            return result
        }
    }

    func getDataFromFile(name: String , type: String) -> [String] {
        let pathFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type)
        let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOfFile: pathFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        let fullContent = contentString.components(separatedBy: ["#"]).map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "") }.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
        return fullContent
    }

    @IBAction func nextRecordButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let firstString = stringsFromFile.first else {
            playerLabel.text = ""
            return
        }

        playerLabel.text = firstString
        stringsFromFile.removeFirst()
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, он хороший, но тот что ниже подходит мне больше. Если бы я мог отметить два ответа, ваш бы тоже отметил )

Comment: @JiosDev Вы всегда можете проголосовать за понравившийся ответ.